# ngRepeat keep re-creating

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jonataswalker/dbxmbxu9/) that simulate my issue. I'm using `ng-repeat` to create some nodes. But these nodes are to be used by another library (Openlayers) which "move" (`appendChild`) these nodes to another place in the `DOM`.

So, a fight for these nodes is happening. Is there a way to tell `ngRepeat` to stop re-sorting, re-creating (not sure about the best term)?

http://jsfiddle.net/jonataswalker/dbxmbxu9/

#### Markup

```html
<button ng-click="create()">New Record</button>
<div data-label="Created here">
  <div 
      id="hint-{{$index}}" 
      class="hint--always hint--right" 
      data-hint="{{row.desc}}"
      ng-repeat="row in rows track by row.id"
      on-render>{{row.desc}}
  </div>    
</div>
<div id="wrap" data-label="I'd like all to be here"></div>
```

#### JS

```js
app.controller('ctrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.rows = [];
  $scope.count = 0;
  var wrap = document.getElementById('wrap');

  $scope.create = function(){
    var c = $scope.count++;
    $scope.rows.push({
      id: c,
      desc: 'dummy-desc-' + c
    });
  };

  $scope.move = function(div){
    wrap.appendChild(div);
  };
}]);
app.directive('onRender', ['$timeout', function ($timeout) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function (scope, element, attr) {
      if (scope.$last === true) {
        $timeout(function(){
            scope.move(element[0]);
        });
      }
    }
  };
}]);
```

Comment: You should post relevant code here at SO, links rot once that happen your question will not be useful to future users

Comment: "I'm asking two librairies to alter the same dom without communicating and I wonder why this ends a mess"  The answer to the question is propably : nope, there is none. Stop using ng-repeat, compile your div manually instead using $compile service and append them to the dom, that's the way to go here.

Comment: @PierreGayvallet, yeah, I guess you're right but is there a way to bind these nodes to an object?

Comment: which nodes? you have a directive which holds a reference to your element. so instead of calling `move` on your element, you could just create a clone of it which you could move. you could work with `ngIf` as well, like `ng-if="!row.isMoved"` after you moved it, so it won't display in your `ngRepeat`

Comment: `scope.move(element.clone()[0]);` ? however, the whole code should be revised (no dom manipulations in the ctrl, onRender shoul'd not know about move method at all, etc.)

Comment: Are you in control of when the other library moves an element? Do you for example tell the other library when to take action by calling a function, like in your example?

Comment: @JonatasWalker of course you can, you can append the cloned element during the link method to your own array of element if you really need to keep a reference

Comment: Thanks guys, @PierreGayvallet, Kryptik, sbedulin, there are some distinct ideas that I have to think a bit. tasseKATT no, I don't have any control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end, I had to give up using `ng-repeat`. Thanks for all comments.

The solution I found is to use [`$compile`](https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/docs/api/ng/service/$compile) service and let the DOM manipulation freely.

http://jsfiddle.net/jonataswalker/y4j679jp/

```
app.controller('ctrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.rows = [];
  $scope.count = 0;
  var wrap = document.getElementById('wrap');

  $scope.move = function(div){
    wrap.appendChild(div);
  };
}]);
app.directive('button', ['$compile', function($compile){
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope){
      var div = document.getElementById('c1');

      scope.create = function(){
        var c = scope.count++;
        var row = { id: 'hint-' + c, desc: 'any desc #' + c };
        var index = scope.rows.push(row) - 1;

        var html = [
          '<div id="'+row.id+'"',
          'class="hint--always hint--right"',
          'data-hint="{{rows['+index+'].desc}}"',
          'data-index="'+index+'"',
          'on-render>{{rows['+index+'].desc}}</div>'
        ].join(' ');

        angular.element(div).append($compile(html)(scope));
      };
    }
  };
}]);
app.directive('onRender', ['$timeout', function ($timeout) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function (scope, element, attr) {
      $timeout(function(){
        scope.move(element[0]);
      }, 2000).then(function(){
        $timeout(function(){
          scope.rows[attr.index].desc = 'changed .... ' + attr.index;
        }, 2000);
      });
    }
  };
}]);
```